# End Observable interval when route changes in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-routing

I start a interval in an Angular component, but it keeps making requests even after I change the route. How can I stop the interval?

```
//returns an observable
getAllPolls() {
    return Observable.interval(2000).switchMap(() => this._http.get('https://xq4kftam4k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/polls2'))
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should save subscription to observable:

```
this.subscription = getAllPolls().subscribe(...);
```

And implement OnDestroy interface:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```